# Is my workaround for the minimum character limit okay?

Tags: discussion, comment, editing, suggested-edits

I tried to edit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816784/819001), simply by adding 2 pairs of parentheses which fell short of the 6 character minimum limit.

So I cancelled the edit and suggested the change via a comment, then the OP [did the edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3816784/revisions).

Is that an okay usage of a comment if I am unable to edit due to the limit?

Comment: I'd say that it was never a bad idea to propose a  needed correction to the OP.  Probably a good idea to then delete the (now unnecessary) comment after the correction is made though people (including myself) often forget to do that.

Comment: You might try adding `${}$` at the bottom of the post. The result will be invisible and will be seen by whoever approves the edit, who can delete it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy using MathJax in this form is not to be encouraged.  Frankly some expliciit dummy text at the end would be relatively better. Like: "*Please remove this placeholder sentence.*"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to suggest edits to a post's author via comments - the purpose of comments is to improve answers and this behavior falls within that purpose. The minimum character limit is mostly a crude measure to prevent certain abuses of the suggested edit system*, not a judgement on which edits are useful. Note that comments are often used to suggest edits for other reasons as well - for instance, if one wishes to make an edit that may conflict with the author's intent, it's better to suggest that to the author in comments rather than apply it directly. It is good practice to delete such comments once the relevant edit has been applied.

(*Also: this limit does not apply to users with reputation 2000+, who can edit freely)